# Splitting a comma separated string into multiple words so that I can loop through each word

Tags: bash, split

I want to split a string for use with a for-loop in Bash. For example, I have this string

```
hello,my,name,is,mindia
```

and I want to split it into individual words so that I can loop through each word. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple way is to use word splitting to array:

```
s="hello,my,name,is,mindia"
```

you set input field separator to ,:

```
IFS=,
```

and then you split the string to array:

```
a=( $s )
```

result:

```
for word in "${a[@]}"; do echo "- [$word]"; done
```

Comment: can you please explain this `"${a[@]}"` ?

Comment: Beware that with this method, `IFS` is globally set... you can have surprises later if you forget about it.

Comment: When you have array "xxx", and you want to iterate over it's elements, it's the syntax to use. "${xxx[@]}" is changed to "${xxx[0]}" "${xxx[1]}" ...

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - Well, you can: `IFS=, a=( $s )`.

Comment: Actually, if you're willing to set `IFS` globally, you might as well not define any arrays at all. Just go along: `s=hello,my,name,is,mindia; IFS=,; for i in $s; do echo "$i"; done`

Comment: `IFS=, a=( $s )` will globally set `IFS`.

Comment: It doesn't set globally for me. echo $IFS afterwards shows previous IFS

Comment: Try it more thoroughly: `s="a,b"; IFS=, a=( $s ); for i in $s; do echo $i; done`, will surprise you. Maybe you mean `echo "$IFS"` (with _quotes_) to check the value of `IFS`? I'll be happy to answer the question _why do you need quotes in echo to check the value of IFS?_ if you ask it as a new question.

Comment: Good point. Apparently `echo $IFS` is bad test. Should be `echo "$IFS"`

Comment: `printf %s "$IFS" | od -c`

Answer (score 3):

Using pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and no `split` (or maybe you meant `cut`):

```
string="hello,my,name,is,mindia"
IFS=, read -r -a array <<< "$string"
# at this point your fields are in the array array
# you can loop through the fields like so:
for field in "${array[@]}"; do
    # do stuff with field field
done
# you can print the fields one per line like so
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
```

*Caveat*. If you're trying to parse a csv file, it will break sooner or later, e.g., if you have a line like

```
field 1,"field 2 is a string, with a coma in it",field 3
```

*Good point*. There's a good point, though, compared with the other answers: if your fields have spaces, this method still works:

```
$ string="hello,this field has spaces in it,cool,it,works"
$ IFS=, read -r -a array <<< "$string"
$ printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
hello
this field has spaces in it
cool
it
works
```

Another good point is that the `IFS` is not globally set; it is only set for the `read` command: no bad surprises later when you forget you've globally set the `IFS`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern substitution:

```
s="hello,my,name,is,mindia"
for i in ${s//,/ }
do
    echo $i
done
```

Here is a version that can handle whitespace:

```
while IFS= read -r -d ',' i; do
    printf "%s\n" "$i"
done <<<"${s:+$s,}"
```

Comment: This will also cut the string at spaces: it fails e.g., with `s="hello,my,name,is,mindia,and this field has spaces in it,ooops"`

Comment: The OP did not specifically say this is required so I don't see this as a major problem.

Comment: I added a version that handles whitespace anyway.

Comment: Regarding your edit: you have a side effect when the string is empty or its last field is empty...

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks for the spotting the bug. I fixed the empty string case, but I consider the treatment of trailing commas to be a feature rather than a bug. I think `"a,,b,"` should be split into `"a"`, `""`, `"b"`, `""` if empty fields are to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
root$ s="hello,my,name,is,mindia"
root$ for i in $(echo "$s" | tr "," "\n"); do echo $i;done

hello
my
name
is
mindia
```

---

***Fixed the spaces issues:***

```
s="a,b,c   ,d,f";
a="";
while [[ $s != $a ]] ; do 
    a="$(echo $s | cut -f1  -d",")";
    echo $a;
    s="$(echo $s | cut -f2- -d",")"; 
done
```

and the output:

```
a
b
c
d
f
```

Comment: Just like tom's answer, it will breask if any element has spaces.